# What does a dollar sign mean in mongodb in terms of groups?

Tags: mongodb

According to the docs, a "$" is reserved for operators. If you look at the group operator however, values need to have a dollar prefixed. These values are not operators. What does it mean in this context then? Example below:

```
db.article.aggregate(
    { $group : {
        _id : "$author",
        docsPerAuthor : { $sum : 1 },
        viewsPerAuthor : { $sum : "$pageViews" }
    }}
);
```

Why does pageViews need a leading dollar sign? I've tried it locally and it doesn't work without the dollar sign.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You use `$field-name` format, when you want to reference a field from the **original or intermediary document**. Here you are summing up all the page views grouping them by author.

Answer (score 32):

In this case "$string" means you want to use the *value* of the key named "string" in the processed document.  Contrast with "string" which would be a literal string.

Answer (score 19):

[`$<field>` is short for `$$CURRENT.<field>`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#field-path-and-system-variables):

> "$" is equivalent to "$$CURRENT." where the CURRENT is a
>   system variable that defaults to the root of the current object in the
>   most stages, unless stated otherwise in specific stages. CURRENT can
>   be rebound.

And, ["Unless documented otherwise, all stages start with `CURRENT` the same as `ROOT`."](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables)

Finally:

> "`ROOT`: References the root document, i.e. the top-level document, currently being processed in the aggregation pipeline stage." [Reference: System Variables](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables)

I.e. `ROOT`, and therefore `CURRENT`, is the document being grouped, and `$<field>` accesses a property of `CURRENT`.

**Note**:

> `CURRENT` is modifiable. However, since `$<field>` is equivalent to `$$CURRENT.<field>`, rebinding `CURRENT` changes the meaning of `$` accesses." 
>   [Reference: System Variables](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables)