# Convert array of objects to array of strings in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I am looking at the following [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-unwind-example).

The following inserts documents into a collection `classes`.

```
db.classes.insertMany( [
   { _id: 1, title: "Reading is ...", enrollmentlist: [ "giraffe2", "pandabear", "artie" ], days: ["M", "W", "F"] },
   { _id: 2, title: "But Writing ...", enrollmentlist: [ "giraffe1", "artie" ], days: ["T", "F"] }
] )
```

And the `members` collection:

```
db.members.insertMany( [
   { _id: 1, name: "artie", joined: new Date("2016-05-01"), status: "A" },
   { _id: 2, name: "giraffe", joined: new Date("2017-05-01"), status: "D" },
   { _id: 3, name: "giraffe1", joined: new Date("2017-10-01"), status: "A" },
   { _id: 4, name: "panda", joined: new Date("2018-10-11"), status: "A" },
   { _id: 5, name: "pandabear", joined: new Date("2018-12-01"), status: "A" },
   { _id: 6, name: "giraffe2", joined: new Date("2018-12-01"), status: "D" }
] )
```

They use the following aggregation to join the two collections on the array field, `enrollmentlist`.

```
db.classes.aggregate( [
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "members",
            localField: "enrollmentlist",
            foreignField: "name",
            as: "enrollee_info"
        }
   }
] )
```

Which returns the following:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "title" : "Reading is ...",
   "enrollmentlist" : [ "giraffe2", "pandabear", "artie" ],
   "days" : [ "M", "W", "F" ],
   "enrollee_info" : [
      { "_id" : 1, "name" : "artie", "joined" : ISODate("2016-05-01T00:00:00Z"), "status" : "A" },
      { "_id" : 5, "name" : "pandabear", "joined" : ISODate("2018-12-01T00:00:00Z"), "status" : "A" },
      { "_id" : 6, "name" : "giraffe2", "joined" : ISODate("2018-12-01T00:00:00Z"), "status" : "D" }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "title" : "But Writing ...",
   "enrollmentlist" : [ "giraffe1", "artie" ],
   "days" : [ "T", "F" ],
   "enrollee_info" : [
      { "_id" : 1, "name" : "artie", "joined" : ISODate("2016-05-01T00:00:00Z"), "status" : "A" },
      { "_id" : 3, "name" : "giraffe1", "joined" : ISODate("2017-10-01T00:00:00Z"), "status" : "A" }
   ]
}
```

How can I reduce `enrolle_info` just to be an array of strings with all of the `name`s?

This is the result I am after:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "title" : "Reading is ...",
   "enrollmentlist" : [ "giraffe2", "pandabear", "artie" ],
   "days" : [ "M", "W", "F" ],
   "enrollee_info" : [
      "artie",
      "pandabear"
      "giraffe2"
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "title" : "But Writing ...",
   "enrollmentlist" : [ "giraffe1", "artie" ],
   "days" : [ "T", "F" ],
   "enrollee_info" : [
      "artie",
      "giraffe1"
   ]
}
```

I have also looked into using multiple joins by introducing the `pipeline` field inside the `$lookup` operation. I am able to use a `$project` to get an array just with `{"name": "example"}` but I am not sure how to remove the `"name"`. I have tried using an `{"$unwind": "$enrollee_info.name"}` but that does not give me what I want. Do I need to introduce another stage to my aggregation pipeline *after* I do the join?

Comment: You can introduce an `$addFields` stage after the `$lookup` - and use the `$map` operator to transform the `"enrollee_info"` as you are expecting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that I was over complicating this. I was able to achieve my desired result by doing the following:

```
db.classes.aggregate( [
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "members",
            localField: "enrollmentlist",
            foreignField: "name",
            as: "enrollee_info"
         }
   },
   {
      $project:
          {
              "_id": 1,
              "title": 1,
              "days": 1,
              "enrollee_names": "$enrollee_info.name"
          }
   } 
] )
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Reading is ...",
        "days": [
            "M",
            "W",
            "F"
        ],
        "enrollee_names": [
            "artie",
            "pandabear",
            "giraffe2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "But Writing ...",
        "days": [
            "T",
            "F"
        ],
        "enrollee_names": [
            "artie",
            "giraffe1"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Great answer. I often forget the difference between `{ $project: {  "enrollee_names": "$enrollee_info.name" } }` (which is what you're doing), vs `{ $project: { "enrollee_info.name": true } }`. The former accesses the names directly using [$/expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215640/1175496) syntax; [example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sULQvRxm6UA), which creates an **array of strings**. Whereas the latter just projects, creates an **array of objects** where each object contains only the string property, [example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pqC3u0sR-go)